# How to remove identical query parameters from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, frontend

I need to remove duplicated query string parameters from the URL

input example
http://example.com/?foo=42&bar=43&foo=42&bar=43

need it to be

Expected output:
http://example.com/?foo=42&bar=43

I'm using this jquery code, but doesn't work

```
function removeDuplicate(url) {
            url = decodeURIComponent(url);                  // decode the url,remove %5B becomes
            var query = url.split('?')[1];                  // get only the query
            var parts = query.split('&');                  // split the query into parts
            var params = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
              var nv = parts[i].split('=');
              if (!nv[0]) continue;
              var value = nv[1] || true;
              if (params[nv[0]] && params[nv[0]].indexOf(value)) {
                params[nv[0]].push(value);
              } else {
                params[nv[0]] = [value];
              }
            }
            url = url.split('?')[0] + '?';
            var keys = Object.keys(params);
            for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
              url += keys[i] + '=' + params[keys[i]].join('+');
              if (i !== keys.length - 1) url += '&';
            }
            return url;
          }
          removeDuplicate(window.location.href)
```

Is that code correct or am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: Note that your post doesn't actually contain a question. You told use what you need to do, but you're not done: you still need to tell us what code you wrote, how that didn't work, and where you got stuck in trying to debug it. If you have no code yet, [it is almost certainly too early to post here](/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ways to make it done:

```js
const link = "http://example.com/?foo=42&bar=43&foo=42&bar=43"

const params = link.replace(/.*\?/g, '')                    // replace everything before '?'
                   .split('&')                              // split by '&'
                   .filter((e, i, a) => a.indexOf(e) === i) // filter duplicates
                   .join('&')                               // join by '&'

const res = link.replace(/\?.*/g, '?' + params)             // replace link params with params without duplicates

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working great

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```js
//var current = document.getElementById("current").innerHTML =
  //window.location.href;
var current = 'http://example.com/?foo=42&bar=43&foo=42&bar=43';
console.log('current', current);
var splitUrl = current.split('&');
console.log(splitUrl);
var newUrl = splitUrl[0] + '&' + splitUrl[3] ;
console.log(newUrl);
```

Just uncomment the first two lines and comment the third line out. That's it.

Comment: Thanks for the effort.